# How to generate random variables with Box-Cox distribution in Python?

Tags: python, random, lambda, data-generation

is there any way to generate random numbers in Box-Cox distribution using known mean, std.dev and lambda? Say, I have used random.gauss(mu,sigma) and random.lognormvariate(mu, sigma) to generate normally and log-normally distributed random variables. How can I do the same for Box-Cox case? How can I introduce lambda along with the mean and standard deviation?

Comment: http://adorio-research.org/wordpress/?p=4532 ?

Answer (score 0):

[**Sci.py**](http://scipy.org) has a box cox (aka. [power normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Cox_distribution)) distribution for a variable. [From their documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.powernorm.html#scipy.stats.powernorm):

```
from scipy.stats import powernorm
numargs = powernorm.numargs
c = [0.9,] * numargs
R = powernorm.rvs(c, size=100)
```

Comment: Thank you, Lego...Can you please clear me how 'powernorm' is utilizing mean, standard deviation and lambda? What does is mean by c?

Comment: @user30337 To be honest, I've not used Sci.py very much, and not at all for statistical purposes. I'd recommend reading through the documentation, all I could offer from here is vague regurgitations from the documentation anyway.